# python-How to solve KeyError: 2?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a dict which is formatted as `{int:[]}`

When I was trying to set value to a key-value pair where the value list is NULL, I got `KeyError: 2`

```
tags = {}
tags.setdefault(int,[])
for tag_id in (db.session.query(PostTagRel).filter(PostTagRel.id == post_id).first().tag_id.split(',')):
            tag = db.session.query(Tag).filter(Tag.tag_id == tag_id).first().tag_name
            tags[post_id].append(tag)
```

What should I do?

Comment: `setdefault` sets default value for a concrete key, not for a type of key. A `defaultdict` might serve your purposes: `from collections import defaultdict` `d = defaultdict(lambda: [])`

Comment: First, you should not redefine reserved names like ```dict```, as you will not be able to use original object further. Second, ```dict.[0].append(1)``` is syntactically invalid

Comment: Please edit your question to show the *actual* code you used, and the traceback.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: Or just `d = defaultdict(list)`: no need for the `lambda`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson aw, that's even more intuitive. Thx!

Comment: @schwobaseggl: Well, kinda. It *looks* nice, but I'm not sure it's particularly newbie-friendly, since there are a number of steps to understanding why it works (i.e., that `defaultdict` takes a zero-argument callable, and that `list` when called with no arguments generates a new empty list).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to set a general default value for all keys, you can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)    
d[0].append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of index formatting not properly done: just try

df.reset_index(inplace = True)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with pandas. It hasn't anything named `df`. Did you answer by accident to another question than the one you intended to answer?